# How do I configure Apache to run multiple instances?

Tags: configuration, apache2, init.d

Specifically, I have two httpd.conf files:

```
/etc/apache2/httpd.conf

/etc/apache2/httpd_2.conf
```

How should I modify the /etc/init.d/apache2 script so that instances of Apache will be invoked for both configurations?

The apache2 script is currently standard/unmodified.

Comment: I thought we can't use httpd.conf in apache2...

Answer (score 1):

see https://serverfault.com/a/397236

alternatively, is it possible to solve your problem with different vhosts?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: on the one hand i understand your concern about bit-rot and disappearing links. on the other hand i do not believe in content duplication and prefer to have one place for a piece of information where it can (possibly) receive future updates. i will turn my answer into a community wiki, so other people can copy over the information.

Comment: Given that this is Ask Ubuntu, you should actually link to http://serverfault.com/a/397309/270721 instead